# Nodeview how to get the data

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, monodevelop

I am using monodevelop, and did a nodeview, now I want to get the data of the selected field  just clicking the mouse
how can ido that?
I would like to try to use target signals. but what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data of the selected node by `your_nodeview.NodeSelection.SelectedNode`.

Depending on what you mean by "just clicking the mouse", you can use either the `NodeView.NodeSelection.Changed` event, or the `EventBox.ButtonPressEvent` event.

1) The `NodeView.NodeSelection.Changed` event is raised whenever the selected node of your nodeview is changed. In particular, when you click the mouse on some node that is not selected, it becomes selected and the event is raised. You can see an example of using this event [here](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpNodeViewTutorialExamples).

2) If you wrap your nodeview in an eventbox, then you can catch the event that the mouse is clicked on your nodeview. You can see an example [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.EventBox).